# One DateFormat to another DateFormat using SimpleDateFormat, without using external lib

Tags: java, regex, datetime

I'm trying to get the following bit of code to work with both input `Strings`. It works for the one without the dash (this is a limitation of `SimpleDateFormat`). I get the `ParseException` for the second input. `JodaTime` has been a suggestion in related posts, however, I can't use that and I'm on Java 6. I'd like to avoid regex solutions, though, a simple one for the format I have that works for both Strings would do. I'm going to drive home now, and check this out again in a couple of hours, with updates on what I find.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class testcc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 EDT 2014";
//      String input = "Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 GMT-400 2014";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df.parse(input);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DateFormat dfTarget = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy");
        System.out.println(dfTarget.format(date));


    }

}
```

Comment: `"It works for the one without the semi-colon"` -- what semi-colon do you mean?

Comment: and why the strange inport: `import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.streamhtmlparser.ParseException;`?

Comment: I meant dash. Thats the wrong exception. Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: Can't you use `"Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 GMT-400 2014".replaceAll("[\\-]", " ");` ?

Comment: No, replacing it with space won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely the case that the source of the date `String` (a GWT extension widget) is returning it incorrectly within the context of `SimpleDateFormat`.  That is, since `z` expects a colon (`GMT-4:00`), not having that fails.  I ended up with something silly like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class testcc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String input = "Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 PST 2014";
        String input = "Wed Jul 02 12:00:00 GMT-400 2014";
        int pos = input.indexOf('-');
        if (pos == -1)
            pos = input.indexOf('+');
        if (pos != -1) {
            input = input.substring(0, pos + 2) + ":"
                    + input.substring(pos + 2, input.length());
        }

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df.parse(input);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DateFormat dfTarget = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy");
        System.out.println(dfTarget.format(date));
    }
}
```

Are there any cases that I missed given the String will always either be: `"Wed Jul 02 12:00:00 GMT-400 2014"` or `"Wed Jul 02 12:00:00 EST 2014"` or `"Wed Jul 02 12:00:00 PST 2014"`, and the likes?